# Fazer pesquisa dentro de uma session

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, session

Tenho uma função na `controller` que me retorna um `JSON`, que pego num `JQuery` e monto minha página. Eu, armazeno o retorno dela em uma session, conforme abaixo:

---

```
SessaoUtil.SalvarSession("PegaHotelPacote", package.Buscar((SessaoUtil.Recuperar("sessionId") != null ? SessaoUtil.Recuperar("sessionId").ToString() : ""), tbSearch));
```

---

Agora, depois do resultado gerado, tenho uns filtros que eu preciso fazer funcionar. Eu preciso agora, pesquisar nessa session. Tipo: O resultado me trouxe 10 htéis, com seus preços, qde quartos e etc... Bem, quero agora pesquisar o Hotel Melia, por exemplo, através de um textedit em minha página. Tudo isso no jquery, pessoal. Como eu faria isso? Chamei esse campo de `txtNomeHotel`, conforme `HTML` abaixo: Tudo está numa `Jquery`, eu apenas peguei o campo, pois senão ficaria extremamente grande o post deste forum.

---

```
<div class="select-group">;
     <input name="txtNomeHotel" placeholder="nome do hotel" />;
</div>;
```

Comment: obrigado Eduardo. Como eu coloco em tags? Antes vinha automático, mas agora como eu faço?

Answer (score 1):

Crie em seu `controller` um método responsável por fazer a pesquisa, e então chame esse método via ajax, e reconstrua a lista de hotéis com os itens retornados da chamada:

Método do controller:

```
public JsonResult FindHotel(string nome)
{
    var result = db.Hoteis.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(nome)).ToList();
    return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Agora é só chamar esse método do controller via ajax assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: @Url.Action("FindHotel", "Controller"),
    processData: true,
    data: { nome: $("#txtNomeHotel").val() },
    success: function (listaHoteis) {
        for (var i = 0; listaHoteis.length; i++)
        {
            var hotelDados = listaHoteis[i];
            // recriar a lista de hoteis
        }
    }
});
```

E coloque um ID no seu input:

```
<div class="select-group">;
     <input id="txtNomeHotel" name="txtNomeHotel" type="text" placeholder="nome do hotel" />;
</div>
```

Comment: Uma pergunta. Como eu faço para ao sair do campo com tab executar a pesquisa?

Comment: Resolvi. Coloquei no onblur do text e funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda. O post pode ser fechado. Não sei como se faz isso ainda.

Comment: É só marcar a resposta como aceita. Veja o link para entender: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)